# Show weather on taskbar in Windows 10, but not "news and interest"

Tags: windows-10, taskbar

In Windows 10, How do I --

1. Show weather (xx degrees Sunny) on taskbar
2. Not show "News and Interest" -- I don't want news or interest or watch videos or games
3. Open the Weather app when I click on the weather icon

Do they even do this kind of easy & convenience stuff any more?

Related, but not duplicate: [How can I force "news and interests" to only show weather on the taskbar?](https://superuser.com/questions/1730409/how-can-i-force-news-and-interests-to-only-show-weather-on-the-taskbar)

I want the icon respond to my click and open Weather app.